# Simple Cycle - Image Issues

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to bring out the image in a list format and cycle through them using Simple Cycle - however the title heading rotates fine but the image is not being shown on the website. So if you look at the left hand side on the homepage under the social media icons there are adverts that will cycle through. On inspecting the element and viewing the image tag it shows a valid image but the image size is being shown as 0x0 then the natural size of the image. I cannot seem to figure out what is going on here. I've tried CSS tweaks but no luck so far. Am i missing something obvious here?

Site: http://bit.ly/1tiPrZO

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.simpleCycle = function (options) {

    // Create some defaults, extending them with any options that were provided
    var settings = $.extend({
        interval: 6000
    }, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        if ($(this).is('ul')) {
            var $List = $(this);

            if ($List.children().size() > 1) {
                var $Children = $List.children();

                // set container dimensions
                function setContainerHeight() {
                    var height;
                    if (typeof settings.height == 'undefined') {
                        height = 0;
                        $Children.each(function () {
                            var thisHeight = $(this).outerHeight(true);
                            height = height < thisHeight ? thisHeight : height;
                        });
                    }
                    else
                        height = settings.height;

                    $List.css('height', height + 'px');
                }

                function setContainerWidth() {
                    var width;
                    if (typeof settings.width == 'undefinded') {
                        width = 0;
                        $Children.each(function () {
                            var thisWidth = $(this).outerWidth(true);
                            width = width < thisWidth ? thisWidth : width;
                        });
                    }
                    else
                        width = settings.width;

                    $List.css('width', width + "px");
                }

                function setContainerSize() {
                    setContainerHeight();
                    setContainerWidth();
                }

                setContainerSize();
                $List.load(setContainerSize);

                // add classes                  
                $List.addClass('simpleCycleList');
                $Children.addClass('simpleCycleItem');

                // setup
                var index = 0;
                $Children.css('z-index', '1').hide();
                $Children.first().show();

                function showSlide() {
                    var $child = $Children.eq(index);

                    $child.css('z-index', '2');

                    $Children.stop(true, true);

                    $child.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                        $Children.not($child).hide();
                        $Children.css('z-index', '1');
                    });
                }

                function next() {
                    index = (index + 1) % $Children.size();
                    showSlide();
                }

                // setup
                var seIntervalID = setInterval(next, settings.interval);

                // don't scroll on hover
                $List.hover(
                function () {
                    clearInterval(seIntervalID);
                },
                function () {
                    seIntervalID = setInterval(next, settings.interval);
                }
            );
            }
        }
    });
};
```

})(jQuery);

**Script Snippet**

```
$('#LeftAdsBox ul#LeftAdsList').simpleCycle({ width: 215 });

 <div id="LeftAdsBox">
        <ul id="LeftAdsList" class="noBullets">

    <li class="leftAdBox">
        <h3><a href="/products/nails/kits/nailtiques-colour-and-care-kit.aspx?manufacturer=16">Nailtiques</a></h3>
        <div class="adContent">
            <div class="topTextBox">
                Colour &amp; Care Kit
            </div>
            <div class="bottomTextBox">
                <p>RRP £16</p>
<hr>
<p><strong>Our Price<br>
 £12.50</strong></p>
            </div>
            <div class="bottomImageBox">
                <a href="/products/nails/kits/nailtiques-colour-and-care-kit.aspx?manufacturer=16">
                    <img src="http://www.clitheroebeautycentre.co.uk/uploads/cms/carecoulour-gift-box-small-02102012-1243.jpg" alt="Nailtiques">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="clearMe"></div>
        </div>
    </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: You cannot plain-post external links in your question and expect someone to explore your code. Add the minimal code to reproduce the issue right into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah it seems to be working fine, just republished the website and restarted it in IIS and voila. Hmmm strange. Maybe some caching was affecting the left adverts. Doh!